# How can I concatenate matches of 2 dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes. I want to concantate matches of the rows (df1) found in column heads (df2)

```
           df1
index
  1        Reactor1  
  1        FIC-2005

  2       Reactor2
  2       FIC-2007

  .       ...


        df2
index
  0        FIC-2005    FIC-2007   .....
  1       0.005       0.006
  2       0.05        0.06
```

output to df3

```
df3

index      Reactor1        Reactor2     ....
 0
 1         FIC-2005        FIC-2007
 2         FIC-2005        FIC-2007
 3         0.005           0.006
 4         0.05            0.06
```

does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the first test DataFrame as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 1, 'Reactor2' ],
    [ 1, 'FIC-2007' ],
    [ 2, 'Reactor1' ],
    [ 2, 'FIC-2005' ]],
    columns=['index', 'text']).set_index('index')
```

so I added a column name (*text*), which you missed (each column must have a name).

To create the second test DataFrames, I ran:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 'FIC-2005', 'FIC-2007' ],
    [ 0.005, 0.006 ],
    [ 0.05, 0.06 ]]
```

so I accepted default column names (consecutive numbers) and default index
(also consecutive numbers).

As I see from *df1*, each pair of rows, with the same *index*, contains:

- **Reactor name** - the column name to be set in *df2*,
- **Reactor Id** - the value in the top row of *df2*.

To be sure that Pandas makes proper ordering, I deliberately reversed
the order of groups in *df1*.

The first processing step is to create a "dictionary table":

```
df1a = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby(level=0).text.agg(list).to_list(),
    columns=['Reac', 'FIC']).set_index('FIC')
```

where the index is *Reactor Id* (*FIC*) and the value is *Reactor name*.

The result is:

```
              Reac
FIC               
FIC-2007  Reactor2
FIC-2005  Reactor1
```

Then I read the top row of *df2* - the row containing *FID*s:

```
rFIC = df2.iloc[0]
```

The remaining steps are:

- reindex *df1a* with *rFIC*, to get ordering according to
  names in top row of *df2*,
- get column 0 from it,
- convert it to a list,
- set it as column names in *df2*.

The code is:

```
df2.columns = df1a.reindex(rFIC).iloc[:,0].to_list()
```

Now, when you print *df2*, you will see proper column names:

```
   Reactor1  Reactor2
0  FIC-2005  FIC-2007
1     0.005     0.006
2      0.05      0.06
```

Of course, to get the job done, *df1* must contain as many row pairs
as the number of columns in *df2*.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo!! Helped me a lot